# docker-machine install fails due to 'Couldn't read CA cert' error

Tags: docker, boot2docker, docker-compose, docker-machine

I am trying to setup `docker-machine` locally on my Windows machine and I followed the install instructions at the [Docker Machine Page](https://docs.docker.com/machine/).

Per the instructions, I ran the following commands in my bash terminal

To install Docker client binary

`$curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.3.0/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe > /bin/docker-machine`

and to install Docker machine binary

`$ curl -L https://github.com/docker/machine/releases/download/v0.3.0/docker-machine_windows-amd64.exe > /bin/docker-machine`

when I try to run `docker-machine -v` I get the following error

`FATAL[0000] Couldn't read ca cert 'C:\Users\Me\.boot2docker\certs\boot2doker-vm\ca.pm: open 'C:\Users\Me\.boot2docker\certs\boot2docker-vm'\ca.pem: The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`

I did some searching and came across a few posts, but can't really see any connection to what would be causing my issues...

https://github.com/hypriot/kitematic/pull/1

https://github.com/docker/machine/issues/908

Comment: which files are actually present? maybe `docker-machine -v` will fail until after you created the machine (i don't use windows so i don't know)

Answer (score 2):

I installed docker machine today on my Windows 7 machine and run the command without any problem.

Did you use boot2docker before on your machine? If you did, it might be related as mine is a clean machine without any pre-existing docker installations.

Answer (score 1):

Its referring to boot2docker environment.

see this:
DOCKER_CERT_PATH="/Users//.docker/machine/machines/dev"

Answer (score 0):

I got the same answer and was able to resolve it by changing the path pattern to be unix-style in the environment variable.

Inside msysgit bash shell:

```
export DOCKER_CERT_PATH=/C/Users/Me/.boot2docker/certs/boot2docker-vm
```

This resolved boot2docker.

Note that I also tried using `docker-machine` before using `boot2docker` which previously failed with the same error. That was not resolved the same way boot2docker could be resolved. For now only boot2docker is working for me.